# UX theme patcher that works for Windows 10 Insider Preview build 10656?

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, windows-10, color

### Scenario

I frequently use 3rd party themes to personalize the look of Windows OS.

To apply a 3rd party theme (in its full functionality meaning as Explorer colorization) need to patch some windows system files (**themeui.dll**, **uxtheme.dll** and **uxinit.dll**)

---

### Problem

Now I did a fresh installaton of **Windows 10 Insider Preview build 10565** but any UX-Theme patcher that I've tried works properly, they seems to patch the files without trhowing any error but I can't use the 3rd party theme that I've been using for **Windows 10 build 10240**, this theme:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/puheucyeb32qfx7/Windows+10+Black+Edition.rar

Then I'll assume the UXTheme patchers I've tried are not prepared for my Windows build.

---

### Question

Is there an UX-Theme Patcher that works for **Windows 10 Insider Preview build 10565**?.

---

### Requirements

- Gratis (Free or Open Source)
- Works for **Windows 10 Insider Preview build 10565**

---

### Research

Software that I tried:

- **[Universal Theme Patcher v1.5](http://www.themebin.com/customizations/universal-theme-patcher-v15/)**
- **[UxStyle Community Edition v0.2.4.2](https://github.com/riverar/uxstyle/releases)**
- **[UXTheme Multi-Patcher v14.2](http://www.windowsxlive.net/uxtheme-multi-patcher/)**
- **[UltraUXThemePatcher v3.0.4](https://www.syssel.net/hoefs/software_uxtheme.php?lang=en)**

Note that I've tried each one in a clean way by doing snapshots in a virtual machine to avoid messing patches.

Comment: This sounds like that you'll have to have a little patience and wait out the preview version to become stable. Then the Ux theme patchers will have time to catch up, and correct any mistakes/changes Microsoft has done...